# Ubuntu NAS login credentials

Tags: networking, login

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Desktop. I can't find the NAS login credentials in the GUI?

If you open the 'Files' icon a window opens which shows the default collection of folders such as home, desktop, starred, etc. At the bottom of that list is an additional function called "+Other Locations" which, once clicked, will display any set of all visible network attached devices including storage.

Where do I input the login credentials for the visible NAS? (Yes my NAS has login credentials, no I don't want to remove them, no I don't want the refrrenced in a static file) There's no popup requesting login, there's no right click to "login as", nor any setting that access the NAS with a different set of credentials.

Comment: *Network Aware Storage* is usually a device, and not a protocol. NAS devices can use various protocols, and that can also be influenced by options used at setup (of the NAS device, or server providing NAS or file-serving functions). Some NAS devices are restricted to CIFS, others can use NFS etc.. and you've given no specifics as to how your NAS was setup  (*windows assumes SaMBa/CIFS*). How you use it is your choice; I've put credentials in a file where I selected the location, and just put that location as a parameter in my *file system table* (so the system can find it) but you can choose.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Desktop; I suggest you apply security fixes asap, especially if your system is online. You can refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ for the ISO release of 22.04.3, but installed systems upgraded **before** this date, and if you system still reports as 22.04.2 you're behind on applying security upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Connect To Server" at the bottom of the Files window.

You will be prompted for your credentials.

[image]